# If $o(a),o(b)\gt 1$ and $o(a)$ and $o(b)$ are co-prime then $o(a)o(b)$ divides $|G|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

Let $G$ be a finite group and $a,b\in G$ such that $o(a),o(b)\gt 1$.

Prove that if $o(a)$ and $o(b)$ are co-prime then $o(a)o(b)$ divides $|G|$.

Well, I'm not quite sure how to start. I found out that if $o(a)$ and $o(b)$ are **not** co-prime then the statement is false. Yet I don't have an idea how to use the fact that $o(a)$ and $o(b)$ are co-prime to prove the statement.

Can you please give me an hint how to start the proof?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you need to find a subgroup of G of size o(a)o(b). What about the group generated by ab?

Comment: @peterwebb that subgroup need not be the size you want - eg a 2 cycle and A 3 cycle in $S_3$

Comment: In general if $a,b$ are coprime and both divide $n$ then their product divides $n$. Think what happens to any prime dividing $a,b$  By Lagrange this is your setup

Comment: @Mathmo123 I understand why your first sentence is correct. But in the second part you told me to think what happens to any prime dividing $a,b$. Why? It is possible that $|G|$ isn't prime. Isn't it correct?

Comment: The second sentence tells you how to prove the first sentence. Any prime power dividing $a$ or $b$ must divide $n$, so $ab$ divides $n$

Comment: @Mathmo123 From the fact that $ab$ divides $n$ I know that $o(ab)$ divides $n$. I'm trying to figure out why $o(a)o(b)$ divides $n$. I'll read your answer again and comment in few minutes.

Comment: @Mathmo123 I'm sorry but I still don't get the second sentence. I understand why $ab$ must divides $n$ but I don't understand why should I look for a prime power dividing $a$ or $b$. For example, in $S_3$ if we take an element of order $2$ and an element of order $3$ and we multiply them we get another element of order $3$ (rotating) which divides $n$. But I don't understand why $o(a)o(b)$ must divide $n$.

Comment: Ah I see the confusion. I should've used different letters. If $x,y\in \mathbb N$ are coprime and divide $n\in \mathbb N$ then $xy\mid n$. You can prove this by considering the prime powers dividing $x$ and $y$. This is the exact setup you have by Lagranges theorem

Comment: @Mathmo123 But in $S_3$, you can take two elements of order $2$ which clearly each one of them divides $|S_3|=6$ but yet, the product of their orders ($4$) doesn't divide $6$.

Comment: The orders of two elements of order $2$ are not coprime.

Comment: You are right. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Mathmo123 I think I understand now. Every $n \in \mathbb N$ can be factored into product of primes. If $x,y\in \mathbb N$ are co-prime then their product must divide $\mathbb N$ because $x,y$ are co-prime which divide $\mathbb N$. Thank you very much .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subgroup $\langle a \rangle$ generated by $a$ has $o(a)$ elements, hence by Lagrange we have $o(a) \mid \#G$. Analogously, $o(b) \mid \#G$. Since $o(a)$ and $o(b)$ are coprime, it immediately follows that $o(a)o(b) \mid \#G$.

**Edit:** In general, if coprime numbers $k, \ell$ divide $N$, then it follows that $k\ell \mid N$. Indeed, let us show that $e_p(k\ell) \leq e_p(N)$ for all prime $p$. If $p \nmid k, \ell$ this is clear. Suppose $p \mid k$. Then $p \nmid \ell$ so $e_p(k \ell ) = e_p(k) \leq e_p(N)$ as $k \mid N$. Similarly, if $p \mid \ell$ we have $e_p(k \ell) = e_p(\ell) \leq e_p(N)$ because $\ell \mid N$.

(Note: $e_q(M)$ is the number of prime factors $q$ in $M$, i.e. the largest $t$ such that $q^t \mid M$.)

Comment: This is what I'm trying to understand, Why "it immediately follows that $o(a)o(b) \mid \#G$". Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand your point. The only thing I'm trying to understand now is what would happen if I used your statement for $a,b$ which aren't co-prime. (For example two reflections in $S_3$).

Comment: I understand it much better now. Thank you very much for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\lcm}{\mathrm{lcm}}$This has nothing to do with groups. It's just that if $x, y, z$ are positive integers, and both $x$ and $y$ divide $z$, then $\lcm(x, y)$ divides $z$. In this case 
$$
\lcm(x, y) = \frac{x y}{\gcd(x, y)} = x y.
$$

Comment: Yes, For some reason I didn't understand it in the first time. Thank you.

Comment: It does have something to do with group theory, you need to know that the order of an element divides the order of the group

Comment: @Belgi, granted, but it seemed to me (perhaps wrongly) that OP was past that.